# Caching and Rendering

Tags: cache

We just have experienced a massive hit (traffic) on our site due to a campaign and have noticed that the craft caching solution is not really working well for the templates/html. We are wondering if there is anything else and how we can set it up to cache to MEMCACHED or any other system instead of the database.

I found some interesting posts on [Is there a way to override the template caching system?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/2464/is-there-a-way-to-override-the-template-caching-system)

Thanks!

PS also the render controller is not performing and is taking over 1s to complete. Any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

The `{% cache %}` tag will only write to the database.

You don't provide many details, so all I can do is offer some general advice.

I'd double check how you're using the `{% cache %}` and make sure that you're not over-caching your data or caching lots of static data that might not need it.

You can always through something like [Varnish](https://www.varnish-cache.org/)/[Fastly](https://www.fastly.com/) in front of Craft to help with template caching.

You can tell Craft to use things like memcache with the [cacheMethod](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/config-settings#cacheMethod) config setting, but that only affects Craft's non-template data caches.

Comment: Hi Thanks Brad, We have  had a look at Fastly and Varnish and will probably go that route.